# jQuery Quicksand ignores overflow:auto on animation

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, quicksand

I'm using the jQuery plugin Quicksand to list some documents for my users to access, I have several hundred documents so I only show a few of them from the beginning.

The list (ul) is built to show about 20 document titles at a time, and the rest is hidden. Like [this](https://www.dropbox.com/s/dauiikq5ht55yib/DefaultList.png). At the bottom of the list you have a link to *Show more*, and when you press it more titles are loaded. Instead of expanding the height of the list the parent div has the property `overflow` with value `auto`.

The list is built by a javascript, it loads the documents from a MySQL database and hides all documents but a specified number. When you press "Show more" ("Visa fler" in Swedish, as showed in the pictures) it reloads the documents and excludes some additional documents form the hide function.

The problem is this: When I press *Show more* it loads more titles but the list ignores `overflow: auto` and the list expands over the entire page, like [this](https://www.dropbox.com/s/1mylwxdihwgx05q/ListWhileLoading.png). After a second or so, when it has finished loading, the `overflow`-property is applied and everything is as it should be, but it doesn't look very good when loading.

Do you have any ideas how to solve this?
Do you need to know anything else?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

I found one solution. I added `atomic: true`, I lost some animation, but it doesn't flow outside of the parent div anymore.

Comment: +1 because I had the same problem on mobile devices and your method solved the problem

Answer (score 0):

From a quick look it seems that it might be do to plugin setting inline styles (width and height) on the container. You might want to override them after the transition ends, e.g.,

```
target.quicksand(source, {}, function () {
   target.css('width', '');
   target.css('height', '');
});
```